# Retrieve child of Parent in firebase database with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database setup and am trying to create a tableview in my Swift application. In the code i've attached, you'll see 'Athens' and it's children.

What I'd like to accomplish is to create a tableView that has the title of the Market(Athens in this case) and the user can click on Athens and it'll display another tableView that has it's children (Beef in this case) and all it's attributes.

I am able to display the children of Athens in a tableView but I can't figure out how to query Athens from the firebase database.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
  "Markets" : {
    "Athens" : {
      "Beef" : {
        "name" : "Beef",
        "price" : 12,
        "salePrice" : 6
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseRef.child("Markets").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild("Athens") {
            print("Athens inside")
        }else{
            print("Nothin inside")
        }
    }
```

Try to use this code if you have additional questions ask me